# One Apache virtual site doesn't work while all the rest do

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I'm at a a complete loss right now and have researched and researched to no avail.

I use DigitalOcean and have an Ubuntu 14.04 Droplet, running the Apache web server. I have about 15 virtual hosts. One of them *suddenly* just stopped responding. I get a @The requested URL `/test.htm` was not found on this server@ error. I can take an existing virtual host and switch to the same directory as the non-working one, and it works perfectly - so it's *not* a permissions issue. I deleted the non-working host and re-created it. Doesn't work. My .conf files all look the same (minus the obvious URL  and directory). Nothing is showing in the error log.

Please note: This used to work. It did for over a year. Nothing has been done to the server.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/informeddev
ServerName subdomain.domain.com
<Directory /var/www/informeddev>
allow from all
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you add the websites config file?

Comment: @JoeyMartin: Use the edit function (and formatting tools). Comments are useless for config excerpts.

Comment: do not mix 2.2.x (allow from all) with 2.4 directives (require all granted)